# How to load Vuforia QCAR tracking file data during runtime in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, augmented-reality

I am working on Augmented reality using Vuforia sdk, and i want to load 3d object on runtime, i want to fetch it from web-service and load it when i need that, So basically my question only is this how can we load any .h file on run time. First is this possible that we can load it on runtime and if possible then how can we do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have dynamic data, putting it into a .h file doesn't make sense.  Headers are only useful while the program is being compiled, not at run time.

Comment: Yes i know that .h file parse at compile time but Using vuforia sdk, it gives you .h file of 3d object which include vertices of 3d object, so i want to do this on run time.

Comment: What's in the .h doesn't change when it's used in terms of its role as a header.  On the other hand, if you simply want to open it in your program as a text file and interpret the content as data, that should be OK.  Then you would use it like any other download and ignore the fact it's a header.  What you do with the 3D information is then up to your own code.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK vuforia just puts arrays of vertical, triangles, etc. into h file. So you don't need to load h file in runtime (and this is impossible, there is no h files when programm is running). Instead you need to get those arrays and give them to vuforia

Answer (score 0):

just download that file from network, store it within application directories and load it like the sample data bundled with the app

```
NSString * pathToDownloadedFile; //should have path to your file

QCAR::DataSet *dataSet = nil;
QCAR::TrackerManager& trackerManager = QCAR::TrackerManager::getInstance();
QCAR::ImageTracker* imageTracker = static_cast<QCAR::ImageTracker*>    (trackerManager.getTracker(QCAR::Tracker::IMAGE_TRACKER));
dataSet = imageTracker->createDataSet();
dataSet->load([pathToDownloadedFile cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], QCAR::DataSet::STORAGE_ABSOLUTE);


imageTracker->activateDataSet(dataSet);
```

Comment: isn't that for datasets not object3d headers? if so how to load both xml and dat files with given answer?

Comment: when you task vuforia to load X.xml it will also load X.dat from the same path , but Vuforia is only AR engine for recognizing trackables, for 3D display you need 3D engine , if you want easy starting point for vuforia , see nineveh.gl AR sample which also loads 3D model from files (which would be easy to download during app runtime) : http://nineveh.gl/downloads/